# Not able to read plist file in swift 2.1

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, plist

I am trying to read the plist file i have created. I am able to read the Info.plist file, but when i try to read newly created file it give's me nil value for the path. Below is the code i am using

```
let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Config1", ofType: "plist")
    if let dict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path!) {

        print("Plist:\(dict)")

    }
```

Comment: Have you included it in the project and added to the app target?

Answer (score 0):

Check Your Plist file path , it must be in the same folder where your info.plist file , you can check it by

- go to your Project folder and copy your plist file to the root of your project folder
- make two copy of your plist file one in the root folder and other in sub-folder

try to run your app , if not nil try to find out  what is the correct path

Comment: let name = NSBundle.mainBundle().infoDictionary!["CFBundleName"] as! String

Comment: Thanks everyone. It was an issue at my end. The file was created at wrong path.

Comment: Good to hear that , if your problem is resolved  please close question by mark the answer .